# Why I didn't get the "PE\0\0"?

Tags: c#, .net, portable-executable, coff

From PE specification:

> At location `0x3c`, the stub has the file offset to the PE signature.
>   This information enables Windows to properly execute the image file,
>   even though it has an MS DOS stub. This file offset is placed at
>   location `0x3c` during linking.
>
> **2.2. Signature (Image Only)**
>  After the MS DOS stub, at the file offset specified at offset `0x3c`, is a 4-byte signature that identifies the
>   file as a PE format image file. This signature is “PE\0\0” (the
>   letters “P” and “E” followed by two null bytes).

I try read these bytes:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

class Program {
  const String fileName = @".\some_application.exe";
  const Int64 peMarkerPosition = 0x3c;

  static void Main(string[] args) {
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open,
      FileAccess.Read)) {
      Byte[] marker = new Byte[4];
      fs.Position = peMarkerPosition;
      fs.Read(marker, 0, marker.Length);
      // Now I expect 'marker'has such bytes: "PE\0\0".
      fs.Close();

      foreach (Byte b in marker) {
        Console.Write(Convert.ToChar(b)); // But I see other values...
      }

      Console.WriteLine("\nPress any key for exit...");
      Console.ReadKey();
    }
  }
}
```

But the `marker` variable has `0x08`, `0x01`, `0x00` and `x0x00` bytes (first and second are not `P` and `E` chars)... Why I get such result?

Comment: As your answer says, and the quoted text says *"After the MS DOS stub, at the **file offset specified at offset 0x3c**"*...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The PE header itself does not start at offset 0x3C - rather, there's a pointer there (a 32-bit file offset from the beginning of the file) to where the PE header starts.